# Undo drawing a polygon vertex (google maps API v3)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to find a way to create an undo button for drawing that works similarly to the undo button that is available while editing the polygon.

To be more precise, whenever a user inserts a point on the map which is for example a vertex of a polygon, he should have an option to undo his last (point/vertext) insertion.

Currently it doesn't exist as an existing functionality and I was hoping that it would be easy to implement it in the application I'm developing, but to me it seems there's no way to approach to the objects and layers created on the map before they are complete.

It's either that in v3 API there's almost everything exposured except this, or that I'm looking at the wrong place.

Apart from 'polygoncomplete' there are no other useful drawing events for shapes and it seems that the maintaned state for drawing activities is deeply rooted and scattered as I couldn't just go and replace map object and canvas elements with their previous versions.

Any hopes?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do and post some code!

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear enough even just by reading the title. Anyway, I just made an edit and hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Why don't you build the polygon by yourself? There is a [Polygon class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon).

Comment: As far as I'm familiar with Polygon class, which for example I'm using to draw (show saved) polygons for which I got vertices stored in database (it's totally different part of the app), I don't see how could I use it to capture vertices which are made during the drawing and not after the polygon is complete. There's no reference to the polygon object being created until it's finished (drawingManager event "onpolygoncomplete").
A user must be able to draw polygons by himself and the app should provide a way for users to undo every point (vertex) they insert until the polygon is completed.

Comment: Yes. If you forget about the drawingManager, you could toggle a *drawing mode* of yours, listen for map clicks, use polylines to draw a shape, and once complete, convert it to a polygon. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Just don't tell me that your suggestion was more in a way that I should recreate the whole DrawingManager :)
update: yeh, sorry, was typing in the same time. I guess your suggestion is the only way. I'll look forward to it and calculate the technical debt. Thanks a lot for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

I've created script based on [google manual](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/delete-vertex-menu) for vertex deleting. The main function is simple, prototype is based on `google.maps.OverlayView`.

```
function DeleteMenu() {
  this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
  this.div_.className = 'delete-menu';

  var menu = this;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function(e) {
    menu.removeVertex();    
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
DeleteMenu.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
```

Gist with code is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc26301a4fb740c2ff26a8b22ff24ad4). Use [jsbin sandbox](http://jsbin.com/qiluyinube/edit?html,js,console,output) to play with it.

View [example page](http://output.jsbin.com/qiluyinube), just click on the map to build your path, you can see undo button.